# Get a nice success notification message from trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying since two weeks to get a success message from `MySQL`.

For example, in PHPmyadmin if you set a trigger containing the following line

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "My personal error text"
```

You get a *nice* red error and the execution is cancelled

I want to get a nice green message on execution to notify that one of my condition has been met `IF new.city=='CHICAGO'`

Any Idea? i'm searching since 2 weeks now

**I we can get an error message, can we get a success message?**

A success message from phpmyAdmin

[image: A success message from phpmyAdmin]

An error i created

[image: An error i created]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, that's not something phpMyAdmin is designed to do -- you're trying to find a way to hook in to the messaging system in a way that phpMyAdmin isn't expecting. For that matter, MySQL doesn't really expect you to send *success* messages; only in the case of failure.